# How to add a .label class with different colors to each category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a forum that has many categories. I want to label each category with different colors. I'm using Foundation 6 .label class for each category name which I'm going to set another class like `.red` `.blue` and so on to go with the specific category. How would i go if i have a category like "Site News" and i want to set it to be red?

The code below shows you a list of the topics with the category it belongs to.

```
<% @topics.each do |topic| %>
 <div class='title'>
  <%= link_to topic.title, topic %>
 </div>
 <div class="category label">
  <%= link_to topic.category.title, category_path(topic.category.id) %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are categories set? or are they user generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer* This works if your category title's are pretty much set, because you will have to add each title in the hash in the solution below.

I would personally use something like [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) or just roll my own presenter, but this *could* go in your model...I am not putting this in a helper, because I try to avoid helpers if I can, as they clutter up your view scope.

```
def label_class
  label_class_map[title]
end

private

def label_class_map
  {
    'title-one' => 'red',
    'Site News' => 'blue'
  }
end
```

Hashes are fast and not as ugly as conditionals. That is why I choose them for this sort of logic. Obviously if statements, case statements, etc would all work, but I try to avoid them at all costs.

```
$ category.title = 'Site News'
$ category.label_class
# => 'blue'
```

Now, in your view, you can apply it as follows.

```
# view

<div class="category label <%= topic.category.label_class %>">
  <%= link_to...
</div>
```

*Update*

If you would rather go about this without adding something like draper or your own presenter pattern, the below will get the job done as a helper.

```
module CategoriesHelper
  def label_class_for(category)
    label_class_map[category.title]
  end

  private

  def label_class_map
    {
      'title-one' => 'red',
      'Site News' => 'blue'
    }
  end
end

# your view
<div class="category label <%= label_class_for(topic.category) %>">
```